# Нет пробела в заголовке на странице профиля

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, профиль-участника

Это происходит, когда открываешь чей-то профиль и смотришь на заголовок окна в браузере.

> [image]

Comment: transifex:5401 (нужны две галки)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Будет исправлено когда мы загрузим переводы из Transifex в следующий раз.